# A variable in my code won't define properly

Tags: python, debugging, variables, math, pygame

This is my code for a maths program I am making for high school. I am struggling at the moment because I can't figure out what I've done wrong, it says that `sum1` isn't defined. If someone could please take their time to go through my code and sort it out I would be very grateful.

my error is on this line: (line 130)

`message_to_screen("What is: " + str(sum1) + " + " + str(sum2),
                          black,
                          -100,
                          "medium")`

**Do let me know if I need to clarify anything.**

Thanks!

```
 # Below I am importing the modules that I will need
import pygame
import random
import time
from pygame.locals import *

# This initiates pygame
pygame.init()

# These are my defined colours
white = (255,255,255)
lightGrey = (200,200,200)
black = (0,0,0)
grey = (100,100,100)
red = (255,0,0)
yellow = (200,200,0)
green = (34,177,76)

# This sets the display width and height
display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Major League Mathematics')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

FPS = 30


easyvalues = list(range(10, 100 + 1))
mediumvalues = list(range(100, 1000 + 1))
hardvalues = list(range(1000, 10000 + 1))

# These are my set sizes for my message_to_screen definition
smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 30)
medfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 50)
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 100)
menufont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 80)

# The next 3 definitions define how text is displayed
def text_objects(text,color,size):

# This is an 'if' statement
    if size == "small":
        textSurface = smallfont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "medium":
        textSurface = medfont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "large":
        textSurface = largefont.render(text, True, color)
    elif size == "menu":
        textSurface = menufont.render(text, True, color)

    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def text_to_button(msg, color, buttonx, buttony, buttonwidth, buttonheight, size = "medium"):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg,color,size)
    textRect.center = ((buttonx + (buttonwidth / 2)), buttony + (buttonheight / 2))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def message_to_screen(msg,color,y_displace = 0,size = "small"):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg,color,size)
    textRect.center = (display_width / 2), (display_height / 2) + y_displace
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)


def button(text, color, x, y, width, height, inactive_color, active_color, value = None):
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + width > cur[0] > x and y + height > cur[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, active_color, (x, y, width, height))
        if click[0] == 1 and value != None:
            if value == "easy":
                easyvalues = list(range(10, 100 + 1))
                sum1 = random.choice(easyvalues)
                sum2 = random.choice(easyvalues)
                gameLoop()
            if value == "medium":
                mediumvalues = list(range(100, 1000 + 1))
                sum1 = random.choice(mediumvalues)
                sum2 = random.choice(mediumvalues)
                gameLoop()
            if value == "hard":
                hardvalues = list(range(1000, 10000 + 1))
                sum1 = random.choice(hardvalues)
                sum2 = random.choice(hardvalues)
                gameLoop()
            else:
                easyvalues = list(range(10, 100 + 1))
                sum1 = random.choice(easyvalues)
                sum2 = random.choice(easyvalues)
                gameLoop()

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, inactive_color, (x, y, width, height))

    text_to_button(text, black, x, y, width, height)



def question():
    if value == "easy":
        sum1 = random.choice(easyvalues)
        sum2 = random.choice(easyvalues)
    if value == "medium":
        sum1 = random.choice(mediumvalues)
        sum2 = random.choice(mediumvalues)
    if value == "hard":
        sum1 = random.choice(hardvalues)
        sum2 = random.choice(hardvalues)
    else:
        sum1 = random.choice(easyvalues)
        sum2 = random.choice(easyvalues)
    print sum1
    print sum2
    print sum1 + sum2
    print value


#Here I am trying to enable raw input from the user
def answer():

    answer = ""
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 50)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, [200,250,400,100])


    message_to_screen("What is: " + str(sum1) + " + " + str(sum2),
                      black,
                      -100,
                      "medium")
    input = True
    while input:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.unicode.isdigit():
                    answer += event.unicode
                if event.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                    answer = answer[:-1]


# This is temporary, while I program the rest
                elif event.key == K_RETURN:
                    if answer == sum1 + sum2:
                        message_to_screen("Correct!", green, 0, "large")
                    else:
                        message_to_screen("Wrong!", red, 0, "large")
                elif event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER:
                    if answer == sum1 + sum2:
                        message_to_screen("Correct!", green, 0, "large")
                    else:
                        message_to_screen("Wrong!", red, 0, "large")



                elif event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()


        block = font.render("Answer: " + answer, True, black)
        rect = 210,280
        gameDisplay.blit(block, rect)
        pygame.display.flip()

















## This is a reference so that I can get my code working

##def name():
##    pygame.init()
##    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 360))
##    name = ""
##    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
##    while True:
##        for evt in pygame.event.get():
##            if evt.type == KEYDOWN:
##                if evt.unicode.isalpha():
##                    name += evt.unicode
##                elif evt.key == K_BACKSPACE:
##                    name = name[:-1]
##                elif evt.key == K_RETURN:
##                    name = ""
##            elif evt.type == QUIT:
##                return
##        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
##        block = font.render(name, True, (255, 255, 255))
##        rect = block.get_rect()
##        rect.center = screen.get_rect().center
##        screen.blit(block, rect)
##        pygame.display.flip()












##def input_box():
##
##    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, grey, [(display_width / 2) - 150,(display_height / 2) + 160,300,80])
##    
##
##    for event in pygame.get():
##        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:



# This definition defines a start screen so that my game doesnt play straight away
def startScreen():

    menu = True

    while menu:

# This allows me to quit the game without any problems
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

# This takes away the menu screen and starts the game once you've pressed 'Enter'
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                menu = False

        gameDisplay.fill(grey)
        message_to_screen("Major League Mathematics", black, -200, "menu")


        #button building
        button("Easy", black, 100, 220, 150, 100, lightGrey, white, value = "easy")
        button("Medium", black, 325, 220, 150, 100, lightGrey, white, value = "medium")
        button("Hard", black, 550, 220, 150, 100, lightGrey, white, value = "hard")

        message_to_screen("Select a difficulty to start!", black, 250, "small")
        pygame.display.update()



# This is my main loop that my game will run off
def gameLoop():

    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False




    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()




        gameDisplay.fill(grey)
        answer()
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()


startScreen()
```

Comment: I've just noticed that your question() function is not called anywhere, so we might have a somewhat bigger problem here. What's exactly the level of your programming skills? Do you understand concepts like global variable and variable scope?

Comment: no not really... I'm just starting out with programming so I'm not the best, but in the end I took the pieces from the `question()` function and put them into the `button()` function. Therefore I don't actually need the `question()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside you `question()` function, if value is not equal to `"easy"`, `"medium"` or `"hard"`, it'll bump into an undefined `sum1` variable. As you didn't say exactly in which line the exception is raised, that would be my best bet.

**EDIT:**

OK, the reason I asked if you knew about some variable scope concepts is because I see you have some functions not being called and tries to access variables outside their scope. I strongly suggest you further readings about variable scoping, but as an immediate answer, the following changes in your code should work for you (can't test it from here):

**- In your button function**

```
if x + width > cur[0] > x and y + height > cur[1] > y:
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, active_color, (x, y, width, height))
    if click[0] == 1 and value != None:
        if value == "easy":
            easyvalues = list(range(10, 100 + 1))
            sum1 = random.choice(easyvalues)
            sum2 = random.choice(easyvalues)
            gameLoop(sum1, sum2)
        if value == "medium":
            mediumvalues = list(range(100, 1000 + 1))
            sum1 = random.choice(mediumvalues)
            sum2 = random.choice(mediumvalues)
            gameLoop(sum1, sum2)
        if value == "hard":
            hardvalues = list(range(1000, 10000 + 1))
            sum1 = random.choice(hardvalues)
            sum2 = random.choice(hardvalues)
            gameLoop(sum1, sum2)
        else:
            easyvalues = list(range(10, 100 + 1))
            sum1 = random.choice(easyvalues)
            sum2 = random.choice(easyvalues)
            gameLoop(sum1, sum2)
```

**- In your gameLoop function**

```
def gameLoop(sum1, sum2):

    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()




        gameDisplay.fill(grey)
        answer(sum1, sum2)
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

**- In your answer function**

```
def answer(sum1, sum2):
```

Comment: that's correct. And reading his code, I have the impression he wants sum1 to be global...

Comment: I was looking exactly into this. There doesn't seem to be a global `value` defined, so it surprises me that this is not the variable that raises the error.

Comment: That didn't seem to have helped. I still get the same error.

Comment: Please edit the question informing which line is causing the error, and if possible comment something like THIS IS THE LINE in your code to make it easier for us.

Comment: Updated my answer with something that should work or at least change the error message.